# Drupal 6: How can i add a link to a hook_menu()?

Tags: redirect, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-webform, hook-menu

I have my own module and I implemented a `hook_menu`, I want that one menu-item redirect (The menu has to stay active) to an existing webform page, this page is:  ?q=node/add/webform.

```
$items['adminQuestion/create'] = array(
      'title' => t('Crear Cuestionarios'),
      'page callback' => "What i put here?",
      'page arguments' => array('form_questionnaires'),
      'access arguments' => array('access questionnaires'),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
$items['adminquestion/create'] = array(
  'title' => 'Crear Cuestionarios',
  'page callback' => 'questionnaires_page',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);


function questionnaires_page() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    $output = node_add('webform');
    return $output;
}
```

where webform is an alias of node/add/webform.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use [`drupal_goto`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_goto/6) with the path to redirect to as parameter:

```
$items['adminQuestion/create'] = array(
  'title' => t('Crear Cuestionarios'),
  'page callback' => 'drupal_goto',
  'page arguments' => array('node/add/webform'),
  'access arguments' => array('access questionnaires'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Also note that $items['adminQuestions'] is bad practice: URLS and paths should never be case-sensitive: in fact: in Drupal CamelCase is highly discouraged in any code.

Comment: Is there a way to make the menu does not collapse when I click on that link?

Comment: Why should a menu collapse when you click on it? You probably mean that the menu should remain "active" on the page where you are redirected to? If so: redirecting is not what you want in the first place. Then please update your question. Instead, you want an alias/duplicate menu-item: a menu-item that acts like another menu-item; which is something completely different then a redirect.

Comment: Yes,i want that the menu remains active when i 'm in the other page like a node_load function. i don't use node_load beacuse i don't know the nid.

Comment: actually, according to the drupal coding standards http://drupal.org/coding-standards you are supposed to use camel case on specific cases, like class names.

Comment: Your answer is the only one that works for me on Drupal 7. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **HTTP redirect** by redirect, you can simply use `drupal_goto('path/to/webform')` but it make no sense since you can use the webform path directly. IMO what you need is a `drupal_get_form()`-like API for Webform which is `node_load()`, so  webform will be loaded in your menu path:

```
// Assuming webform node with nid: 237
$items['adminQuestion/create'] = array(
  'title' => t('Create Cuestionarios'),
  'page callback' => 'node_load'
  'page arguments' => array(237),
  'access arguments' => array('access questionnaires'),
  'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Webform implementation of `hook_theme()` takes care of theming the node to form. Alternatively you can just change webform path, if possible in your case.

Comment: How I can find out the nid of the webform's create page?

Comment: AFAIK webform has its own node type, just go to `admin/content/node`, find your webform node and check its nid. (check the edit url for example)

Comment: Is not a webform, is a webform admin page (node/add/webform).

Comment: So simply enable the path module and go to `admin/build/path`, then create a `adminQuestion/create` alias for `node/add/webform`.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, i made the alias but i don't know how to call the alias from the hok_menu...

Comment: Santiago, Please exactly explain what you want to do, so we can help you more effectively. I have no clue about why you need to "call" an alias in the implementation of hook_menu(). Please be more specific.

Comment: how i call an Alias from the hook_menu() item?:
    `$items['adminQuestion/create'] = array(
    $items['adminQuestion/create'] = array(
      'title' => t('Create Cuestionarios'),
      'page callback' => -->"What i put here?"<--,
      'page arguments' => array('form_questionnaires'),
      'access arguments' => array('access questionnaires'),
      'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    );`

Answer (score 0):

Reading the comments, it sounds to me like you want to create a path alias to /node/add/webform.  You don't need to implement hook_menu.

You create aliases at /admin/build/path/add (make sure you have the path module enabled).

Comment: i need the hook_menu beacuse is part of a bigger module. i don't know how to load a page that doesn't have a nid beacuse is a webform admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to make an 'add node page' part of a tab group

```
$items['mynode/new'] = array(
    'title' => 'New Node',
    'page callback' => 'node_add',
    'page arguments' => array('my_node_type'),
    'access arguments' => array('create my_node_type content'),
    'file' => 'node.pages.inc',
    'file path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'node'),
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'weight' => 0,
);
```